# mysql count number of votes in votes table

Tags: php, mysql, count, left-join

I have 3 tables named `election_cand`, `candidate` and `votes`:

`election_cand` table:

```
ele_can_id | election_id | candidate_id
```

`candidate` table:

```
id | canname | canadd | canphone | canmail | candes | canphoto
```

`votes` table:

```
voteid | candidateid | voterid | electionid
```

my tables with data are:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I want the desired result as

[image: Screenshot 2]

I write the mysql query as:

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*, count(voteid) AS numrows
FROM election_cand a
left join votes b on a.election_id=b.electionid
left join candidate c on a.candidate_id=c.id
where a.election_id='$get_ele_id' group by a.candidate_id
```

Comment: Add some data from your tables

Comment: @wajeeh please view now its urgent. kindly give me the solution

Comment: @wajeeh are you available? please review now.

Comment: Yes I'm available, But your schema is very strange, I will try

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

As I see you only need this query:

```
SELECT 
    c.*, COUNT(e.ele_can_id) AS numrows
FROM candidate c
Left Join election_cand e on c.id = e.candidate_id

GROUP BY c.id
```

describe your schema so we can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT 
c.*, COUNT(v.candidateid) FROM candidate c 
LEFT JOIN votes v ON  c.id = v.candidateid 
WHERE c.id IN 
( SELECT candidate_id FROM election_cand WHERE election_id = 4  ) 
GROUP BY v.candidateid
```

Comment: I don't think we should be advocating a join style that was effectively deprecated in 1992

Comment: Hi, @Strawberry, thank you for your reminder, I have updated the SQL query.